# Formatting In TinyMCE Editor

Tags: tinymce, editor, text-editor

In **TinyMce Editor** , we are facing a problem with `break` `(<br/>)`tags. If we press <kbd>Enter</kbd> sometimes it generates a *single break tag* and sometimes it generates *double break tags.*

If anyone knows the relevant solution for this , it will really helpful to resolve this.

As per my understanding about this break tags are generated depends on `editors,text,words, strings and space between  words`.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Safari,Chrome and Internet Explorer...

Comment: using `enter` should make a new paragraph `<p>`, not a double line break, and `shit+enter` should make a single line break `<br />`.

Comment: can you provide a live example? or tinymce.fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out below links which will help you,

1. [TinyMCE Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/naaaab)
2. [Full featured example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)
3. [HTML5 formats](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/html5_formats.php)

Answer (score 1):

There are several [solutions](http://btools.eu/blog/read/tinymce-extra-br-and-p-instead-of-new-lines-bug), first try setting to
    convert_newlines_to_brs: false
**without the quotes** enclosed false.

if this doesn't help you can use this cleanup function

```
function CustomCleanup(type, content) {
  switch (type) {
   // gets passed when user submits the form
   case "get_from_editor":
    content = content.replace(/<br \/>/gi, "\n"); // would be nice if this replace only replaces the brs in a pre block. bur for the moment it is ok.
    break;
   // gets passed when new content is inserted into the editor
   case "insert_to_editor":
    break;
  }
return content;
}

tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    cleanup_callback : "myCustomCleanup"
});
```

Comment: I want to make this formatting before save to database.Because then-only users will know how it ll display in reflecting page.